# Cannot turn on wifi on Galaxy SIII

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-3

For the last month, I am unable to turn on my WiFi. It gets stuck on the message "turning on..." .

I did a factory reset but it didn't help. I have tried to reboot a number of times and also I have enabled/disabled flight mode, but nothing works out for me.

Comment: Are you running a factory ROM, or using a custom ROM and/or kernel? If you're running a custom ROM and/or kernel, the module/firmware may be incorrect. Have you checked the system log? Look at the results from 'dmesg' (run via ADB or a terminal app), specifically the log entries that relate to the wifi adapter.

Comment: I had this same problem when I rooted my device and messed up with some stuffs in Busybox. Hope you didn't try to do some things that could cause that. If you did. Try reloading a new stock rom of your device.

Answer (score 0):

Might very well be a hardware problem as doing a factory reset also hasn't helped. It's best to get your phone checked by an authorized technician.